# Android differences between signed and unsigned .apk files?

Tags: android

How many difference between signed and unsigned .apk files in android?

I know only one when i integrate in-app purchase i have unsigned .apk its gives me error 
`Item version is not same as...`

and also we cant install unsigned .apk file in android device...

is there any other Diffrences ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[the signed apk will contain an extra folder "META-INF", which contains three files:](http://nowherenearithaca.blogspot.in/2011/12/difference-between-signed-and-unsigned.html)

1. MANIFEST.MF
2. CERT.SF
3. CERT.RSA

Answer (score 13):

If you send unsigned apk to customer, they have to enable Unknown sources to be able to install the app. Also Google Play Console doesn't accept unsigned one.

[image]