# Is there any 'issue' in distributing/installing the app signed with developer key?

Tags: android, apk

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10280278/398802)  question on SO tells that the difference is in some files. My question is what difference does it make if I distribute my unsigned apk file, the one found in /bin folder. While publishing on market we have to create a keystore and export signed app but what if I dont go through the full process and just send or distribute the apk that is signed with debug key (say for peer review).

Edit: I'm not trying to put unsigned app on market, just on few devices to check.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any 'problem' in distributing/installing the app signed with developer key ?

The developer key's maximum lifetime is one year. After that, the APK will no longer be usable. And, since that one-year lifetime is set when the key is created (when you first run the Android SDK build tools, or when you regenerate the key), it is conceivable that your APK will no longer work as of, say, tomorrow.

Also, someone who has installed your app with the developer key will need to uninstall it to install your production-signed APK later on, so make sure they understand this.

Also, each developer, by default, has their own developer key, and so I suggest that you be consistent with which member of your development team is creating APKs for use outside your firm.

Otherwise, I cannot think of any particular problems with using such an APK for testing purposes, client previews of works-in-progress, etc.

Comment: Yes now I got it! Thanks a lot for this explanation. You and your books are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

There are also two different versions of *signed* apks.

By default, your IDE will sign your apk with a *debug* key, which will allow users to install it on their device if they check the "use for development" boxes in the Settings.

In order to publish to the marketplace, you have to sign it with a *release* key, which allows users to install it without enabling additional settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't publish an unsigned .apk. The Android devloper console won't let you.

Comment: More importantly, you cannot *run* an unsigned `APK` file. No device or emulator will support it.

Comment: Yes of couerse, sorry forgot to mention that :)

Comment: I'm aware of market that it won't allow..thats fine with me.  @CommonsWare But I have been installing and running the apk file found in /bin directory in different devices

Comment: it is auto-signed by your debug key

Comment: @AyushGoyal: The unsigned APK has `-unsigned` in the name. Just because it is in `bin/` does not mean that it is unsigned. As WebnetMobile.com points out, by default, your APK is signed by the developer (a.k.a., debug) signing key. I am fairly confident that neither the emulator nor devices will install an unsigned APK.

Comment: That means I was going for "The difference between the two keys?" Is there any 'problem' in distributing/installing the app signed with developer key ?