# Difference between exporting an unsigned and signed app package

Tags: android, export, apk

How do I differentiate between exporting the app for launching it as to whether I should select the **unsigned** option or **signed** option.
There are many posts, but I didn't find anything useful as to describing which one should be used in which case.

Please if anyone can elaborate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android differences between signed and unsigned .apk files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280278/android-differences-between-signed-and-unsigned-apk-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only **Signed** Apps can be published on Play Store. You **can't publish Unsigned** app.
Therefore if you want to publish your app to play store then always export as Signed app package.