# Xamarin Studio: Can't Sign and Distribute Xamarin Forms Android App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have a Xamarin Forms project in Xamarin Studio and want to create a self-signed apk file. But after I created an archive, sign & distribute, select my created certificate and defined the file path, I got the error message: One or more errors occured.
Only the first time, after creating the certificate worked, but I had to rebuild my app. After googling, I found a hint, which could be the problem: the sign & distribute process not asking after password again. Thanks for help.

Comment: There should be logs under `Help -> Open Log Directory` which should have `monodroid` / `ide` logs that should tell you what the actual error is. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/#Xamarin_Studio

Answer (score 0):

There is step by step guide to understand the process:

https://blog.xamarin.com/android-archiving-and-publishing-made-easy/

if this is not what you need then, every time you compile an .apk is generated for you inside the .Droid/bin/Debug folder of your project:

com.XXX.XXX-Signed.apk

com.XXX.XXX.apk

To understand the difference between a signed .apk file and a unsigned one you can read:

[Android differences between signed and unsigned .apk files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280278/android-differences-between-signed-and-unsigned-apk-files)

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/